# facebook app fails to open stream

Tags: facebook

I have made an app that registers users for a certain cause. The app gets the email, name from their FB account.

```
39: $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)."&client_secret=".$secret."&code=".$code;

40: $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

41: $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email&".$access_token;

42:$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
```

I get an error in lines 40 and 42

```
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/*********/index.php on line 40
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/*********/index.php on line 42
```

but only after try to evaluate the fields given by users and not when first time launching the app. Is here any mistake in this code or should I look somewhere else in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) for the correct way to implement server-side auth, Specifically Step 6.

> The body of the response that your code will receive and parse will
>   look like this:
>
> `access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN&expires=NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_UNTIL_TOKEN_EXPIRES`

You should extract the access_token for usage.

Whenever you have problems with authentication, your first step should be to run the `access_token` in the [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to ensure a user and app are tied to it with the correct scopes.

Comment: I am using the access_token. I did some changes after considering step 6 but it seems that nothing has changed. Also you are right the debugger says, can access data from url.

Comment: $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response , $params);

$_SESSION['access_token'] = $params['access_token'];

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];**

Comment: No, if you take the data the endpoint returns 1:1 unparsed, you are __not__ using the access token, because that endpoint returns _more_ than _just_ the access token.

Comment: @CBroe indeed that is what the debugger says, that I aint using the access token BUT I am following the FB code in documentation by word.

Comment: No, you are not following it word for word, if you don’t parse the response to _extract_ the access token.

Comment: parse_str($response , $params); Am I not?

Comment: ---$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();---$user_str=file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$accessToken);---   $user=json_decode($user_str,true);  looks like this works